# refer to df.columns in a list containing several df

Tags: python, pandas

I have several large data frames stored in a list
I want to iter over the columns in those df a change their prefix
I thought of the following code but I want the for loop to iter over the df columns not all the df's

```
files=glob('*_indresp.dta')
df_list=[pd.read_stata(x) for x in files]

for df in df_list:
    df.replace(to_replace=r'^\D+_', value=' ', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`DataFrame.rename()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with the `columns` param.

Also note that you need to add `inplace=True` to save the changes in place.

```py
import re
for df in df_list:
    df.rename(columns=lambda name: re.sub(r'^\D+_', '', name), inplace=True)
```